# Cant float SVG in IE10/11 or Edge12

Tags: svg, css-float, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, microsoft-edge

I've got similar to the attached code (this is stripped down, but the issue persists)

In IE10/10 and Edge12 the SVG won't float to the right of the container, all other browsers I've tested work.

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.wedge-left {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
svg {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wedge-left">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 127 709" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <title>wedge-left</title>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M114.572-.058h13L15.072 709.5H.5L114.572-.058z" fill-opacity=".5" fill="#FFF" />
        <path fill="#e8e5f2" d="M127-.058V709.5H12.928z" />
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>

</div>
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/Myxwvb

Answer (score 1):

In SVG you should be able to supply one of width and height and the browser works out the other dimension (as long as the SVG has a viewBox).

Unfortunately IE doesn't behave as it is supposed to.  You need to supply both a width and a height.

So the fix is to supply a valid width to the SVG:

```
svg {
  width: 53.74px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

The 53.64 comes from the viewBox ratio (127/709) multiplied by the height of the containers (300px).

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.wedge-left {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
svg {
  width: 53.74px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wedge-left">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 127 709" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <title>wedge-left</title>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M114.572-.058h13L15.072 709.5H.5L114.572-.058z" fill-opacity=".5" fill="#FFF" />
        <path fill="#e8e5f2" d="M127-.058V709.5H12.928z" />
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>

</div>
```

Another alternative, which will work in your case,  is to align the SVG to the right of the container viewport using the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 127 709" ... preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet">
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.wedge-left {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
svg {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wedge-left">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 127 709" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet">
      <title>wedge-left</title>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M114.572-.058h13L15.072 709.5H.5L114.572-.058z" fill-opacity=".5" fill="#FFF" />
        <path fill="#e8e5f2" d="M127-.058V709.5H12.928z" />
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I cannot define the width of the SVG as the container height is variable, which is why I've done `width: auto; height: 100%` I tried just adding on the aspectRatio thing but it didnt change anything

Comment: Then you must have done it wrong.  I have now added snippets for each solution. Both of which work fine in IE 11.

Comment: I'll give this another look tomorrow once I'm back then! thanks for the feedback